# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Open Source's [first moderator election](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: MadHatter]

He'll be joining [the existing crew](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank him for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with him as he learns the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking Zizouz212 who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4764755707297792/0).

Answer (score 11):

I didn't realise it was Zizouz212's imminent departure that was driving the election.  Thanks a ton, Ziz; you've been carrying that load, with aplomb, for a long time.

Thanks also to curiousdannii for having the guts to stand.  Contested elections are always better than coronations, but it means someone has to lose, and that takes guts.

And to everyone else: I'll try not to stuff the job up.

Comment: Welcome aboard! [Here be secrets](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26593/open-source-moderators), also known as Open Source's private mod room.

Comment: Congratulations! You'll do a great job!

Comment: Congrat for the diamond :) well deserved

Comment: Congrats @MadHatter!